# Why is import and export in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, import, export

My index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

my main.js code

```
import User from './user.js'

const user = new User('bob',11);
console.log(user);
```

My user.js code

```
export default class User{
    constructor(name,age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

export function printName(user)
{
    console.log(`User's name is ${user.age}`);
}

export function printAge(user)
{
    console.log(`User is ${user.age} years old`);
}
```

the above code is not working at all
it gives the error:
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/user.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Well where is `user.js` located in your installation?

Comment: I got it right it was in the other directory . My bad